# How to get AWS Cognito throw an error if we ask for invalid scope (client credentials grant)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

As of now, Cognito doesn't throw an error if I ask for invalid scope.  It generates access token excluding the invalid scope.  But, in my case, I would like to have Cognito throw an error if the consumer asks for a scope which is not allowed (or which is not available).

Are there any options available?

Comment: There are hooks built into Cognito, I would say try the pre token generation one.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html

Comment: @SándorBakos, unfortunately the pre-auth, pre-token triggers do not get fired for client-credentials grant.  They do fire for auth-code grant.